# Docker: repository name must be lowercase

Tags: postgresql, docker, redis

Im getting errors trying to run my docker containers. I need the postgres and redis connected to my server application.

```
docker pull postgres
docker rm -f syda-postgres
docker run -p 30203:5432 --name syda-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password POSTGRES_USER=root POSTGRES_DB=syda postgres

docker pull redis
docker rm -f syda-inmemory
docker run -d -p 30204:6379 --name syda-inmemory redis redis-server --appendonly yes

docker pull docker.url.ee/syda/server:latest
docker rm -f syda-server
docker run -d -p 30202:8080 --name syda-server --link syda-postgres:postgres --link syda-inmemory:redis \docker.url.ee/syda/server:latest
```

This is the error im getting:

```
Error: No such container: syda-postgres
docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase.
See 'docker run --help'.
Error: No such container: syda-server
docker: Error response from daemon: could not get container for syda-postgres: No such container: syda-postgres.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
docker run -p 30203:5432 --name syda-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password POSTGRES_USER=root POSTGRES_DB=syda postgres
```

That tries to run a container from the image named `POSTGRES_USER=root` with the command/arguments to the entrypoint `POSTGRES_DB=syda postgres`. You need to pass the `-e` for each variable like:

```
docker run -p 30203:5432 --name syda-postgres \
  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -e POSTGRES_USER=root -e POSTGRES_DB=syda \
  postgres
```

Also, note that links are deprecated, you should use a shared network for communicating between containers. This is often done with a compose file. If you need to do it from a script, you could run:

```
docker pull postgres
docker pull redis
docker pull docker.url.ee/syda/server:latest

docker rm -f syda-postgres
docker rm -f syda-inmemory
docker rm -f syda-server

docker network rm syda-net
docker network create syda-net

docker run -p 30203:5432 --net syda-net --name syda-postgres \
  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -e POSTGRES_USER=root -e POSTGRES_DB=syda \
  postgres

docker run -d -p 30204:6379 --net syda-net --name syda-inmemory \
  redis redis-server --appendonly yes

docker run -d -p 30202:8080 --net syda-net --name syda-server \
  docker.url.ee/syda/server:latest
```

Comment: Oh wow thanks! Is there any way I can remove the network before each run of the script too? Like the containers?

Comment: Sure, `docker network rm syda-net`. Do that after the `docker rm` commands to be sure no containers are there.